# Template argument deduction for lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, c++14

I'm trying to make a helper function that executes a lambda/std::function when called if the given weak_ptr is valid. Currently the following code works, but unfortunately, it requires me to define the template parameters. I'm looking for a way to do this with automatic template argument deduction.

```
template <typename DependentType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
auto make_dependent(std::weak_ptr<DependentType>& dependent, std::function < void(ArgumentTypes...)> functor) -> decltype(functor)
{
    return [&dependent, functor] (ArgumentTypes... args)
    {
        if (!dependent.expired()) {
            functor(args...);
        }
    };
};
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the `std::function <void(ArgumentTypes...)>` with a generic template parameter `FunctorType`, but then I'm not sure how I would extract arguments from `FunctorType`. The above code works, the below code is theoretical:

```
template <typename DependentType, typename FunctorType>
auto make_dependent_ideal(std::weak_ptr<DependentType>& dependent, FunctorType functor) -> decltype(std::function<return_value(functor)(argument_list(functor))>)
{
    return[&dependent, functor](argument_list(functor) args)
    {
        if (!dependent.expired()) {
            functor(args...);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: If you put `DependentType` after `ArgumentTypes` you will only have to specify `ArgumentTypes`, since `DependentType` is deducible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem with extracting arguments from your parameter is to not extract the arguments from your parameter.

```
template<typename F, typename C>
struct conditional_forwarder {
  F func;
  C cond;
  template<typename Fin, typename Cin>
  conditional_forwarder( Fin&& f, Cin&& c ):
    func(std::forward<Fin>(f)), cond(std::forward<Cin>(c)) {}
  template<typename... Args>
  void operator()( Args&&... args ) const {
    if (cond())
      func( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
template<typename F, typename C>
conditional_forwarder< typename std::decay<F>::type, typename std::decay<C>::type >
make_conditional_forwarder( F&& f, C&& c ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<C>(c)};
}
// todo: make_dependent_test   

template <typename DependentType, typename FunctorType>
auto make_dependent_ideal(std::weak_ptr<DependentType>& dependent, FunctorType functor)
  -> decltype(make_conditional_forwarder( make_dependent_test(dependent), functor) )
{
  return make_conditional_forwarder( make_dependent_test(dependent), functor);
}
```

much of this will be easier in C++14.

As an aside, there seems to be a fundamental design flaw: the conditional forwarder should probably aquire a `.lock()` on the `weak_ptr`, and then execute `functor` within that lock, so that the precondition (that the resource is held) holds for the entire call of `functor`.

I'm also unsure why you are holding a reference to a `weak_ptr`, when the remote state of a `weak_ptr` can be copied.

In C++14, you can return something like:

```
return [=](auto&&... args) mutable {
}
```

I believe, and the `decltype` stuff also goes away mostly as functions can deduce their return type more easily.

Comment: What does `[=](auto&&... args) mutable {}` mean? Both the parameters part and the `mutable` part confuses me.

Comment: @LB-- Parameters are implicitly typed, a C++14 feature I believe.  `mutable` is a C++11 modifier to a lambda that means the `operator()` on the generated lambda can modify its captured variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd solve your problem in C++14:

```
template<typename DependentType, typename FunctorType>
auto make_dependent(std::weak_ptr<DependentType> &dependent, FunctorType functor) {
  return [&dependent, functor](auto &&...args) {
    if (!dependent.expired())
      functor(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
  }
}
```

I'm using two C++14 features here:

- Deduced return type for `make_dependent`
- A variadic generic lambda with perfect forwarding to call the inner `functor`

**EDIT:** The code above captures `dependent` by reference, as your original code did. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proxy trait class to extract the return type and arguments separately from a single template parameter. The `Trait` class uses the static function `dependent_func` to create the lambda you want to return.

```
template <typename DependentType, typename FunctorType>
struct Trait {};

template <typename DependentType, typename ReturnType, typename... ArgumentTypes>
struct Trait<DependentType, std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>> {
    static std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)> dependent_func(const std::weak_ptr<DependentType>& dependent, std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)>& functor) {
        return [&dependent, &functor] (ArgumentTypes... args) {
            if (!dependent.expired()) {
                return functor(args...);
            }
        };
    }
};

template <typename DependentType, typename FunctorType>
auto make_dependent_ideal(std::weak_ptr<DependentType>& dependent, FunctorType& functor) -> decltype(Trait<DependentType, FunctorType>::dependent_func(dependent, functor)) {
    return Trait<DependentType, FunctorType>::dependent_func(dependent, functor);
}
```

For more info about parsing template arguments in this way, look at this question: [C++ parsing function-type template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314888/c-parsing-function-type-template-argument)